# Freeing a pointer (to a void*) inside of a struct

Tags: c

C newbie here, and I can't seem to figure this one out. So I'm starting to implement a linked-list (just something basic so I can wrap my head around it) and I've hit a snag. The program runs fine, but I can't free() the data stored in my struct.

Here's the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    struct node* next;
    void* data;
    size_t data_size;
};
typedef struct node node;

node* create_node(void* data, size_t size)
{
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = (void*)malloc(size);
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}
void destroy_node(node** node)
{
    if(node != NULL)
    {
        free((*node)->next);
        //this line here causes the error
        free((*node)->data);
        free(*node);
        *node = NULL;
        printf("%s\n", "Node destroyed!");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    float f = 4.325;
    node *n;

    n = create_node(&f, sizeof(f));
    printf("%f\n", *((float*)n->data));

    if (n->next == NULL)
        printf("%s\n", "No next!");

    destroy_node(&n);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this message in the program output:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5b4b1cac: pointer being freed was not allocated

I'm not entirely keen on how this can be dealt with.

Comment: Btw., while not important in this program, you´ve forgotten to assign `node.data_size` in `create_node`.

Comment: @deviantfan yeah, I got distracted but thanks for pointing that out! I woulda missed it for a while.

Comment: @Rust FYI You don't need to (and shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc()` in standard C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> node* create_node(void* data, size_t size)
>     ...
>     new_node->data = (void*)malloc(size);
>     new_node->data = data;
> ```

Here, (1) you are losing memory given by `malloc` because the second assignment replaces the address (2) storing a pointer of unknown origin.

Number two is important because you can't guarantee that the memory pointed to by `data` was actually malloced. This causes problems when freeing the data member in `destroy_node`. (In the given example, an address from the stack is being freed)

To fix it replace the second assignment with

```
memcpy (new_node->data, data, size);
```

---

You also have a potential *double free* in the `destroy_node` function because the `next` member is also being freed.

In a linked list, usually a node is freed after being unlinked from the list, thus the next node shouldn't be freed because it's still reachable from the predecessor of the node being unlinked.

Comment: I chose this answer as correct because a less proficient programmer might have some confusion determining the proper way to implement the previous answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is because when you do:

new_node->data = data;

you replaces the value put by malloc just the line before.
What you need is to copy the data, see the function memcpy

Comment: Yes, I knew it was something simple I was missing. Completely forgot about memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

While you got an answer for the immediate problem, there are numerous other issues with the code.

```
struct node {
    struct node* next;
    void* data;
```

What's up with putting * next to type name? You are using it inconsistently anyway as in main you got node *n.

```
    size_t data_size;
};
typedef struct node node;

node* create_node(void* data, size_t size)
{
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

What are you casting malloc for? It is actively harmful. You should have used sizeof(*new_node). How about checking for NULL?

```
    new_node->data = (void*)malloc(size);
```

This is even more unnecessary since malloc returns void * so no casts are necessary.

```
    new_node->data = data;
```

The bug already mentioned.

```
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}
void destroy_node(node** node)
{
    if(node != NULL)
    {
```

How about:

```
if (node == NULL)
    return;
```

And suddenly you get rid of indenation for the entire function.

```
    free((*node)->next);
    //this line here causes the error
    free((*node)->data);
    free(*node);
    *node = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", "Node destroyed!");
```

What's up with %s instead of mere printf("Node destroyed!\n")? This message is bad anyway since it does not even print an address of aforementioned node.